# invalid_client The OAuth client was not found

Tags: python, oauth, oauth-2.0, google-authentication

I had carefully followed this great tutorail http://www.indjango.com/access-google-sheets-in-python-using-gspread/ , but somehow I can't manage to access my google account. When running the following script, i run into a  *invalid_client
The OAuth client was not found.* error page .

Below is my code:

```
from oauth2client.client import OAuth2WebServerFlow
from oauth2client.tools import run
 from oauth2client.file import Storage

 CLIENT_ID = '<99899xxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com>'
CLIENT_SECRET = '<-oBSqxxxxxxxxxxxxwL2>'

 flow = OAuth2WebServerFlow(
      client_id = CLIENT_ID,
      client_secret = CLIENT_SECRET,
      scope = 'https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds           https://docs.google.com/feeds',
      redirect_uri = 'http://example.com/auth_return'
   )

storage = Storage('creds.data')
credentials = run(flow, storage)
print "access_token: %s" % credentials.access_token
gc = gspread.authorize(credentials)
wks = gc.open("bloggers_contact").sheet1
recipients = wks.col_values(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the carets (`<`, `>`) from `CLIENT_ID` and `CLIENT_SECRET`.